# taking text from textbox and putting into span in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing a self print function by gathering all the HTML from the users screen and putting it into a variable which then displays a pop-up screen so the user can print that information.

```
        var disp_setting = "toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,menubar=no,";
        disp_setting += "scrollbars=yes, height=500, left=100, top=25";
        var content_vlue = document.getElementById("print_content").innerHTML;
        var docprint = window.open("", "", disp_setting);
        docprint.document.open();
        docprint.document.write('<html><head>');
        docprint.document.write('</head><body text="#000000" onLoad="self.print()">');
        docprint.document.write('<table>');
        docprint.document.write(content_vlue);
        docprint.document.write('</table>');
        docprint.document.write('</body></html>');
        docprint.document.close();
```

**UPDATE:** 
OK thanks to many of the suggestions so far I'm starting to make some headway...

What I would like to do is instead of manipulating print_content, I would like to put print_content into a variable (i.e. content_vlue) and then manipulate content_vlue.

```
var content_vlue = document.getElementById("print_content").innerHTML;
$("content_vlue").find("INPUT[type='text']").each(function(i){
var input = $(this);
input.replaceWith("<span class='textinput'>" + input.val() + "</span>";
});
```

**Is there a way to do this?**

Comment: In your update, is the `.print_content` selector a typo? If not, it should be `#print_content` to be equivalent to `getElementById`.

Comment: @Rfvgyhn - Thanks...  that was a typo on my part...  I am now able to access the .html of that div...  I'm still having issues replacing the textboxes though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use a library like jQuery?  It would be pretty straight forward to replace the inputs with span tags once you'd created the page:

```
function cleaninputs(){
  $("body").find("input").each(function(i) {
    var input = $(this);
    input.replaceWith("<span class='textInput'>" + input.val() + "</span>");
  });
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here's a slightly refactored version which should do what you want:

```
function replaceInputs( _which ){
  var cleanHTML = $("#"+_which).clone();
  cleanHTML.find("input").each(function() {
    var input = $(this);
    input.replaceWith("<span class='textInput'>"+ "  " + input.val() + "</span>");
  }); 
  return cleanHTML.html();
}
```

Then replace this line:

```
var content_vlue = document.getElementById("print_content").innerHTML;
```

with:

```
var content_vlue = replaceInputs("print_content");
```

And you should be all set.  For good measure I made a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pcsF3/1/

Comment: RFvgyhn is correct.  Either use tag selector $("div") to get all instances or $("#print_content") to select just one instance by ID.

Comment: @RSG - what does the i in function(i)?

Comment: The i is the index, see http://api.jquery.com/each/ for a full explanation.  It's not necessary in this case, you can safely delete it.

Comment: See my updated question.  Your suggestion put me on the right path...  Just wondering if I can manipulate the html text from within another variable.

Comment: That was the solution!  Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

Using only CSS you can simply hide the border of the text boxes making it look like ordinary text:

```
docprint.document.write('<style type="text/css"> input { border: 0; }</style>');
```

Comment: Yes I could do that and that would take away the border but lets say the textbox was only showing 13 of the 25 characters I want to display the other 12 that are currently being hidden.

Comment: @Jeff well, `input { border: 0; width: 300px; }` should do the trick.. replace `300px` with the width of the container if it's fixed, it's also possible to set the width at runtime using JS code. :)